# The PlaceholderText unable to display in QTextEdit

Tags: qt, designer

I wrote a small program using the qt Designer, but now the PlaceholderText in the program can't be displayed for the first time. It can only be displayed after I type a text and then clear the text. This is why？

[image]

Comment: Please provide some code snippet to show you did and what is wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

I said it wrong, it's a `QPlainTextEdit`, but it doesn't matter. I later regenerated a `QPlainTextEdit` in **QT Designer**. I compared their properties and found that it was the same, but in the end, I reset the `plaintext`. Note that it was reset but not cleared, then the `placeholdertext` is displayed. I thought that clearing `plaintext` would be all right, now I have solved it.

Comment: As I commented under the question, it is highly recommended to have a code snippet. Neither your question nor the answer makes sense because as a reader I couldn't understand what the question was and what the soultion is.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966714/how-to-insert-and-clear-placeholder-in-qtextedit] helps you.