Python | PySide6 | Cursor sticks inside the textbox
Apart from other things, my application window has textbox. I want that when the textbox is focused, the text inside it should be cleared. But after I move out of that textbox, the cursor stays.

#Create textbox01 with Enter Full Name
    self.textbox01 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.textbox01.setText("Enter Full Name")  # Placeholder text
    self.textbox01.setFixedSize(250, 30)  # Set fixed size for textbox
    self.textbox01.setStyleSheet("""
                QLineEdit {
                    background-color: transparent;
                    color: #D9D9D9;  /* Foreground color */
                    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;  /* Border color */
                    font: 12pt "Calibri";  /* Font and size */
                }
            """)
    self.textbox01.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
    self.textbox01.move((self.window_width - self.textbox01.width()) // 2, self.profile_image.y() + self.profile_image.height() + 30)

    # Connect focus events
    self.textbox01.focusInEvent = self.clear_text01_on_focus
    self.textbox01.focusOutEvent = self.restore_text01_on_focus_out

    def clear_text01_on_focus(self, event):
    # Clear text when the textbox gains focus
    if self.textbox01.text() == "Enter Full Name":
        self.textbox01.clear()

def restore_text01_on_focus_out(self, event):
    # Restore placeholder text when the textbox loses focus and is empty
    if self.textbox01.text() == "":
        self.textbox01.setText("Enter Full Name")
    self.textbox01.clearFocus()


Do you want a placeholder? If yes then see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348117/how-to-set-the-placeholdertext-for-qtextedit

The cursor stays because you've not called the base focusOutEvent() of the super class. In any case, that's irrelevant, since QLineEdit already provides the functionality you're trying to get: just use self.textbox01.setPlaceHolderText('Enter Full Name'). If you're using Designer, select the line edit and set the related property in the property editor box. Also, arbitrary fixed sizes and positions are always discouraged, use layout managers instead.

Thank you @musicamante I am just starting out in Python and not yet well versed with it. But yes, I understand fixed sizes and position do not make sense. Have a lot to learn!!

Notes: 1. calling the base implementation is not just about Python, but it's part anything about almost any object oriented programming language that provides classes and subclassing/inheritance capabilities; 2. PySide (as PyQt, from which PySide derives) is a python binding around a framework (Qt) written in a very different language (allowing to use an external library using Python objects and function calls; layout management is not PySide/PyQt specific, but is part of: 1. the QtWidgets module of Qt; 2. almost any UI based toolkit.

A further note: that code and result seems suspiciously based on a YouTube tutorial made by a certain "Hala". It may not be the case, but, if it is, I strongly suggest to completely ignore them: while some of their suggestions are not wrong in principle, the whole explanation and implementation contain a lot of terrible mistakes under many aspects (Qt, PyQt/PySide, Python, design, UI). Just disregard them and then: 1. put more (efficient) efforts in looking for more appropriate tutorials; 2. study the documentation: tutorials are good, but they're not everything.

So, I have already built this application in C# & WPF. I am just now transitioning this to Python. That is why I said I am not well versed with Python yet. Having said that, I am using ChatGTP to help me with Python syntax. I don't look at YouTube tutorials.
